# Using turbolinks in a Rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-4

Just wondering whether there's a way to use turbolinks directly in a rails link_to helper, a quick bit of googling didn't uncover anything of note, here's the type of thing I've tried to no avail.

```
<%= link_to 'Giraffe', giraffe_path(@giraffe), :data-no-turbolink => 'true' %>
<%= link_to 'Giraffe', giraffe_path(@giraffe), :data { :no-turbolink => 'true'} %>
```

I know you can do it in regular links like this

```
<a data-no-turbolink='true' href="/giraffe-130">Giraffe</a>
```

Right now I'm just including the attribute on elements that surround the link such as lis or divs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

**Edit for Rails 5+:** @ManishShrivastava correctly pointed out the different syntax needed for Rails 5 as shown in [Joseph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37999169/4299353).

`<%= link_to('Giraffe', @giraffe, data: { turbolinks: false }) %>`

**For Rails 4 and below**

Originally I thought you needed to use the hash rocket syntax for the symbol but that isn't the case.  You can use a `data:` hash and inside that hash any symbols using  underscores `_` will be converted to dashes `-`.

I think most Rails developers would prefer to see the following (including myself now that I know better):

`<%= link_to('Giraffe', @giraffe, data: { no_turbolink: true }) %>`

But the following also works:

`<%= link_to('Giraffe', @giraffe, 'data-no-turbolink' => true) %>`

Comment: I feel bad about upvoting an answer with 42 votes, even if I really want to. Otherwise, thanks I didn't know about this underscore-dash conversion ! Then it means it's not possible to have the actual underscore in the output ?

Comment: If you want an underscore in the output you would have to use quotes and the hash rocket syntax.

Comment: @ManishShrivastava thanks for pointing out the edit needed for Rails 5.

Answer (score 71):

Turbolinks 5 uses a slightly different syntax

```
<%= link_to "Foo", new_foo_path(@foo), data: { turbolinks: false } %>
```

Source: [Turbolinks Github Page](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#disabling-turbolinks-on-specific-links)

Comment: After upgrading to Rails 5, this is definitively something to look out for. Took me a while to realize that the attribute naming had changed.

Comment: This is for rails 5. This only gonna work. https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/269#issuecomment-297541803

Answer (score 17):

You can use a symbol without problems to generate the following code:

```
 <a data-no-turbolink='true' href="/giraffe-130">Giraffe</a>
```

Just do the following:

```
 <%= link_to 'Giraffe', giraffe_path(@giraffe),
             :data => { :no_turbolink => true } %>
```

Note: `:no_turbolink` will become `no-turbolink` and the value will be converted to JSON automatically using `to_json`, e.g. `true` to `"true"`.

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer. It fixes typos in the original question without giving him a different way.

Answer (score 6):

@Joseph you are right, but only small change:

```
<%= link_to "Foo", new_foo_path(@foo), data: { turbolinks: 'false' } %>
```

when I'm typing `turbolinks: false` doesn't work with bool, works only when I use string for value `turbolinks: 'false'`. So maybe someone help this information ;).

Comment: Wow. Nice catch there. Super helpful. You saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Or Ruby 1.9+ syntax:

```
<%= link_to 'Foo', foo_path(@foo), data: { no_turbolink: true } %>
```

But I ended up dropping turbolinks in favour of [Wiselinks](https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/wiselinks)  which makes behaviour explicit on all links, plus Wiselinks also supports partial update (eg paging), replace state (doesn't pollute browser history, great for column sorting), form submission (great for search forms), redirects, support for browsers without history API, and more intelligent asset change handling.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 7 is now

```
<%= link_to 'Foo', foo_path(@foo), data: { turbo: false } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you'd like to change language using locale, you have do like here:

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Українською"),  {locale: :uk},  
data:{ turbolinks: "false" }%>
```