# Rails javascript only works after reload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

The problem is exactly what the heading says. The javaScript is in the asset pipeline i.e assets/javascripts/myfile.js.coffee In the application.js I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= requier twitter/bootstrap
//= require jasny-bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

This is the coffeescript

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#close").click ->
    $(this).parent().parent().slideUp("slow")




  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker
    dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd"


  player_count = $("#player option").length


  $('#btn-add').click ->
    $('#users option:selected').each ->
      if player_count >= 8
        $('#select-reserve').append("<option      value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>")
        $(this).remove()    
      else
        $('#player').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>")
        $(this).remove()
        player_count++


  $('#btn-remove').click ->
    $('#player option:selected').each ->
      $('#users').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>")
      $(this).remove()
      player_count--


  $('#btn-remove-reserve').click ->
    $('#select-reserve option:selected').each ->
      $('#users').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>")
      $(this).remove()


  $("#submit").click ->
   $("select option").prop("selected", "selected")
```

I can see in the source code on the browser that the javaScript has been loaded, but it only works after I reload the page.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, though I'm not using CoffeeScript. http://pastebin.com/d5QKXydy

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This was a turbolinks problem. Thanks to @zwippie for leading me in the right direction!
The solution was to wrap my coffeescript in this:

```
ready = ->
// functions

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Comment: Thats coffeescript, its the syntax for a function.

Comment: I don't understand, did you put this exact code on top of the code from your question? Did you choose one of the events? Did you nest one within the other?

Comment: Hi @GiovanniDiToro, 
What you need to do is run the code after the `page:load` event. So in my example, I wrapped the code I wanted to run inside a function called ready, and added that as a callback to be run after the `page:load` event.

Comment: @JasonCarty I did that, I called via coffeescript inside JQuery-> $(document).ready ->$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', -> . But I also found out that in IE it works , but firefox auto-completes if value is empty...

Answer (score 75):

For turbolinks 5.0 you must use the **turbolinks:load** event, which is called the first time on page load and every time on a turbolink visit. More info: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads

CoffeeScript code:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  my_func()
```

JavaScript code:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  my_func();
})
```

Comment: I have the exact problem but im using C# and asp.net. Can you please suggest the correct scripting for this? Thanks

Comment: This is the only one that would work for me on new rails 5 app

Comment: @wolfQueen asp.net and C# usually are for server-side.
You should probably look on your client side files (this can be on specific .js files or within your html depending on what you are trying to do)

Comment: Exact same issue, and I was specifically trying to figure out how to modify the turbolink load on a one-off basis. Thanks!

Comment: Spent ages wrestling with this.  You're solution worked for me.

Comment: @MariaLuisa I am having this issue and wish to put the JavaScript and CoffeeScript into my app, however I do not know where to put the two code blocks. Can you tell me where to put them?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. But Joseph N's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227363/using-turbolinks-in-a-rails-link-to/37999169#37999169) worked for me

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 25):

I guess this is a turbolinks issue.

Either remove turbolinks from your project or modify your script to something like:

```
$(function() {
  initPage();
});
$(window).bind('page:change', function() {
  initPage();
});
function initPage() {
  // Page ready code...
}
```

As mentioned [here](http://geekmonkey.org/articles/28-introducing-turbolinks-for-rails-4-0).

Comment: This solution worked for me and Rails 5, but instead of `'page:change'` I used `'turbolinks:load'`.

Answer (score 19):

You can install the [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem to solve the problem without changing your Javascript.

Comment: No longer works with Rails 5. See discussion https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks/issues/56 - the gem has been deprecated.

Answer (score 9):

You can have your jquery.turbolink place at the right position like this

```
 //= require jquery 
 //= require jquery.turbolinks 
 //= require jquery_ujs 
 //= require bootstrap-sprockets 
 //= require turbolinks
```

And in the Gemfile you can install the 
jquery-turbolinks gem

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

Comment: if you have query, then turbo links then jquery.turbolinks you will generate the condition of having to create reloads.  This is the fastest, cheapest and proper answer in my view.  add gem + insert **in the proper order** the require statement in app/assets/javascript/application.js

Answer (score 7):

Rails 5 
Use the jquery.turbolinks gem and using

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you work with JQuery plugins such as [Clock Time Picker](https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker), firstly use jQuery `document ready` function, which causes your script to wait until the entire page is loaded before attempting to run and then you can use `turbolinks:load` event.

```
JQuery(function($) {
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $('.time').clockTimePicker();
  });
});
```

It is good to be situated in your `app/assets/javascripts/... js` file

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying Rails 5.2 and found that `'turbolinks:load'` wasn't getting loaded the first time a page loads.  This is what I needed to do in my CoffeeScript file.

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', ->
  # ... CoffeeScript code here
)

if !Turbolinks?
  location.reload

Turbolinks.dispatch("turbolinks:load")
```