# Rails Dropzone error : html class="fallback" is changed after reload pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with dropzone and file_tags in rails view :

`<%= form_tag '/media_contents', method: :post, class: 'dropzone form', id: 'media-dropzone' do %>
          <div class="fallback">
            <%= file_field_tag 'media', multiple: true %>
          </div>
      <% end %>`

When i start to show a html view , i get this class :

```html
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/media_contents" id="media-dropzone" class="dropzone form">
    <input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
    <input type="hidden" value="ksbt9hMvy3RCzFzqiRJpq+MBw5gbqy/rlWZ7mL1tOGnRjfv+CRWdLrVCdxXJyFCYL73A5H4Vb9lWl+fRA4rE7Q=="
           name="authenticity_token">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="media" name="media">
    </div>
</form>
```

But after i reload this page, i get new html element in file input :

```html
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/media_contents" id="media-dropzone" class="dropzone form dz-clickable">
    <input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
    <input type="hidden" value="WZZn20j4veF2OtEMK12qR06tkGtPpNsgst/Kkan9SyAa3XHTUsLru4G0+vNrh5N0ghGTFyoamxJxLlbYFxq3pA=="
           name="authenticity_token">
    <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div></form>
```

I want to get second view , not first view . But i don't know why , and how to remove first view . Please help

Comment: Anyone ? Please help

Comment: I am using rails 4, and i get this error by turborlink error :[Turborlink error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317816/rails-javascript-only-works-after-reload).