# Highcharts with Turbolinks - Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am using Highcharts with Rails 4 and Turbolinks. I faced the problem of charts not appearing when switching pages.

I fixed this by doing this in the initialization script:

```
var ready = function(){
    Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors,              function(color) {
    return {
        radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
        stops: [
            [0, color],
            [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
        ]
    };
});
//further initialization
}


$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Then it loaded every time I visited the page. But the entire chart is black. I am using pie charts with multiple colors. But only the first time colors are displayed. But in subsequent page visits the colors are all black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting existing colors with radial gradient objects. Then when reload, you are doing this the same but now variable colors is not more string, but is object (I guess).

I think you should change this:

```
Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) { ... });
```

to:

```
var colors = ['#FF00FF', '#FFFFFF' ... '#00FFFF'];
Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map( colors , function(color) { .. });
```

Comment: Hi can you tell me what colors to add to colors array?

Comment: How would I know which colors you need?:) Default colors are here http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors

Comment: Okay Got it :) I was searching for the default colors. Thanks a lot! working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Had exactly the same problem and solved it by disabling turbolink for the page.

Example :

```
= link_to 'My charts page', charts_page_path, data: { turbolinks: false }
```

**Caution :** the way to deactivate turbolinks changed since version 5.0 and the link in this post is for older version.

So if this does not work, check your version of turbolinks :

- For version 5.0+ : use `data: { turbolinks: false }`
- For older versions : use `data: { no_turbolink: true }`

Answer (score 0):

turbolinks is like jquery-mobile. The pages which use turbolinks act like single page applications, so you need to keep state between them. You can make a global variable and check if it is nil, or disable turbolinks for the highcharts pages.

Comment: Okay. I understand that. Thank you. But how do I disable Turbolinks on a page basis?

Comment: you can use data-no-turbolinks in link_to or (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227363/using-turbolinks-in-a-rails-link-to) or try <body data-no-turbolinks> (https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/pull/52)

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting the charts at alll... :(