# View loses CSS link tag after redirect_to

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently developing a web app and I have a slight problem. I have a redirect_to root_path statement in my view's controller that is called if a logic statement returns true. On the page being redirected to, I have a stylesheet_link_tag in the layout view. When I pull up the page manually, this tag loads correctly. However, after the redirect_to statement is used and this page is loaded from it, the stylesheet tag is no longer there. It still loads the application.css file and my application.js file without anyone issues but the pagename.css link tag doesn't even show up.

And here's how the page displays:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu25b.png]

Then once I refresh:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDtzk.png]

PLEASE help me! I would love to know why this is happening and how to fix it. Thank you in advance!

Here are all of the relative code bits:

users_controller.rb

```
...

  def logout
    cookies[:logged_in] = false
    cookies[:user_id] = 0
    redirect_to root_path # Tried using root_url also; didn't fix the problem.
  end

...
```

homepage/index.html.erb (root_path)

```
A bunch of HTML. Not the problem.
```

layouts/homepage.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>...</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'homepage' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header_container">
    <%= link_to "#{image_tag 'logo.png'}".html_safe, root_path %>
    <div class="login tab">
        <span>
            Login
            <%= image_tag "down_arrow.png" %>
        </span>

        <%= form_tag login_path, :method => 'post' do %>
        <% end %>

    </div>
    <div class="register tab">
        <span>
            <%= link_to "Register", register_path, "data-ajax" => "false", :rel => false %>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="main_container">
    <%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I had to add the homepage.css asset to config/locales/application.rb, so here's that:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Labs
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.assets.precompile += %w( homepage.css )
    config.assets.precompile += %w( dropdown.js )
  end
end
```

Comment: what does the console say?

Comment: Started GET "/register" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-04 20:18:50 -0500
Processing by UsersController#register as HTML
  Rendered users/register.html.erb within layouts/register.html.erb (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 14.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[2014-06-04 20:18:50] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body.
 Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true

Answer (score 4):

The problem can be two-fold:

--

**Turbolinks**

Firstly, you *may* have an issue with [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks)

Turbolinks is notorious for preventing styling & javascript changes on pages; as it basically just refreshes the `<body>` tag of your page (keeping the `<head>` intact). Although this is mainly for if you're traversing pages through link clicks (I'm not sure about `redirects`), you basically need to make sure any styling changes can occur even with Turbolinks enabled.

To do this, you need to ensure you're loading *without* calling Turbolinks. To do this, you should [use the `data` `no-turbolink` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227363/using-turbolinks-in-a-rails-link-to), as follows:

```
<%= link_to "link", link_path, data: { no_turbolink: true } %>
```

This will ensure you don't call `turbolinks` when you click that particular link, ensuring a "naked" refresh if you will.

--

**Redirect**

The redirect method might be  the cause of the issue you're facing.

When you mentioned:

> The redirect_to statement is used and this page is loaded from it, the stylesheet tag is no longer there. It still loads the application.css file and my application.js file without anyone issues but the pagename.css link tag doesn't even show up.

The way to fix this is to ensure your `layout` includes the correct `stylesheets`. You've included your `homepage.html.erb` code - I would be eager to say that if `pagename.css` isn't loading, it basically means you're not calling the file correctly.

I would do this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag controller_name %>
```

This will allow you call stylesheets per controller (using the [`controller_name` helper method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/controller_name/class)) - allowing you much broader control of what you're loading on the page