# turn of turbo links when clicking a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I was wondering if this is possible. I have seen stack questions ask this and the answer seems to be:

```
<%= link_to 'Manage', '/manage?id='+blog.id.to_s+'#dashboard', :class => 'btn btn-primary', :data-no-turbolink => false %>
```

But I get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `no' for #<#<Class:0x007f8d5270a440>:0x007f8d54a5af30>
```

So I am wondering what the actual answer is for this. How do you say "don't use turbo links when following this link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14310416/2856441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax. Try:

```
<%= link_to 'Manage', '/manage?id='+blog.id.to_s+'#dashboard', :class => 'btn btn-primary', "data-no-turbolink" => false %>
```

**OR**

```
<%= link_to 'Manage', '/manage?id='+blog.id.to_s+'#dashboard', :class => 'btn btn-primary', data: {no_turbolink: false} %>
```