# Sort array in view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I am trying to sort an array in the view by using link_to's, however I'm not getting any changes in the results.

The view -

```
 = link_to 'Rating', sort: "rating"
 = link_to 'Origin', sort: "origin"
 = link_to 'Meal Time', sort: "meal_time"
```

The controller -

```
 def index
   @recipes = Recipe.order(params[:sort])
 end
 #####
 def sort
  if (params[:order] == 'rating')
    @recipes.order('rating')
  elsif (params[:order] == 'origin')
    @recipes.order('origin')
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :index }
    format.json { render json: @recipe }
  end
end
```

Am I missing something? I was using the ASCIIcast for sortable table columns as it's the most simple solution I've found to this problem. Here's the repo - https://github.com/luchia/eaten.

EDIT: As suggested by wurde, I kept the Turbolinks gem and and changed the code in the view -

```
=link_to('Rating', sort: 'rating', 'data-no-turbolink' => true)
=link_to('Origin', sort: 'origin', 'data-no-turbolink' => true)
=link_to('Meal Time', sort: 'meal_time', 'data-no-turbolink' => true)
```

But this results in a weird bug where the attribute no-turbolink is now a physical part of the [URL (image attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi5MF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've still been unable to get this to work and have tried a number of different solutions including different gems. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue with Rails turbolinks caching, since you are using a link to 'pull' a new index of recipes. Try removing turbolinks to verify.

Here is a Railscasts solution: [Sortable Table Columns](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns)
Here is a relevant StackOverflow QA: [Using turbolinks in a Rails link_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227363/using-turbolinks-in-a-rails-link-to)

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. I removed the turbolinks gem and the results still don't change. Repo can be found [here](https://github.com/luchia/eaten)

Comment: Try keeping the gem, and adding the data element to link_to instead.

Comment: Another test is to issue an ajax request via your links and inspect what's returned.

Comment: I found a railscasts (great resource) for this specific issue of sorting in Rails.