# select2-rails gem is not working on Rails4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, select2-rails

I have tried given documentation for [the select2-rails gem](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails), but my browser console still throws an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

I am using `rails 4.0.1`& `select2-rails 3.5.9.3`

My **application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require select2
//= require jquery.ui.accordion
//= require jquery.ui.menu
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require common
//= require posts
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require owl.carousel
//= require turbolinks
//= require vendor_js
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select#team_select").select2();
});
```

**application.css**

```
*= require select2
*= require_self
*= require jquery.ui.accordion
*= require jquery.ui.menu
*= require jquery.ui.datepicker
*= require common
*= require owl.carousel
*= require lazybox
*= require fancybox
*= require owl.theme
*= require 7531339
*= require_tree .
*= require font-awesome
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.select(:team_id, @teams.collect {|p| [p.name, p.id]}, {include_blank: "None"}, {id: "team_select"}) %>
```

What i am doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if the select2.js is *really* loading?

Comment: Put tour '//require select2' after all the JQUERY plugins ? And remove the 'select' in selector of jquery => $('#team_select').select2();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is surely in **application.js**: According to their [Demo App](https://github.com/argerim/select_2_example/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/application.js), the sequence of requiring JS plugins is as follows:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require select2
//= require select2_locale_pt-BR
//= require_tree .
```

In your case, you have to load `turbolinks` *before* `select2`, leading to:

```
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require select2
//= require jquery.ui.accordion
//= require jquery.ui.menu
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require common
//= require posts
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require owl.carousel
//= require vendor_js
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 1):

I never encountered this issue while using rails 4.1.5 & select2-rails 3.5.9.3.
However, after upgrading rails to 4.2.4, I get the same exact error described in this question:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

I was able to resolve the error by removing the "select2-rails" gem from my Gemfile and replacing it with:

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-select2', '~> 4.0.0'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

On rails 5 using CoffeeScript and turbolinks I had to use the line:
`$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->`
before everything so that the code gets executed when the desired page with the select tag is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and changing the order of JS plugins didn't help.

I ended up removing turbolinks and it's working now. Probably not the best solution but it was the best thing that I achieve after some hours searching.

So, basicly I removed that line from **application.js** file:

```
//= require turbolinks
```

Comment: Instead of removing `//= require turbolinks`, we can modify `link_to` like e.g: `<%= link_to('Giraffe', @giraffe, data: { no_turbolink: true }) %>` [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227363/using-turbolinks-in-a-rails-link-to)