# Rails 5 and select2 error, select2 is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I am trying to use the rails select2 gem, `gem 'select2-rails'`
But when I try to use it with the following order import order, my browser complains that select2 is not a function. From what I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545787/select2-rails-gem-is-not-working-on-rails4) this order should be correct.

javascripts/application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require select2-full
//= require_tree .

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
   console.log('(document).turbolinks:load')
   $("#estimation_patient_id").select2({
       theme: "bootstrap"
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
//= require rails-ujs
```

OR

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

not needed to both

And modify like below

```
(function($){
    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
       $("#estimation_patient_id").select2({
           theme: "bootstrap"
       });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Remember it: sometimes `//= require select2-full` is not working but `//= require select2` is working nicely with all requirements. I recommend to use `//= require select2`.

Comment: I have the exact same order of my require statements as my question, but it works with the function in your answer. thx