# Rails, why does turbolinks stop link_to from showing when I add yield in head?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have added these two lines in my application.html.erb file `<%= yield :gal_img_hover_stylesheet %>` and `<%= yield :gal_imgs_hover_stylesheet %>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>UserGalleryPictureProject</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= yield :gal_img_hover_stylesheet %>
    <%= yield :gal_imgs_hover_stylesheet %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

When these are added the `link_to`s in other actions dont show only on page refresh, they are there in the inspector but are dulled out until I refresh. If I remove `yield` to these stylesheets the `link_to` work fine again. I think it has something to do with javascript as removing `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` in application.html.erb links work fine again too.

Is there a way around this because I want the benefits of turbolinks but im not versed enough on where the error is coming from. Obviously when my javascripts arn't loaded into the browser the link_tos work but want to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable turbolinks on the link_to

`<%= link_to('Model', @model, 'data-no-turbolink' => true) %>`

and try to put your two yield header in the below the turbolinks and css code or in the body tag

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227363/using-turbolinks-in-a-rails-link-to) link here which gives the turbolinks 5 syntax `data: { turbolinks: false }`. I will mark as correct but will have to see why is doing that..