# Download button for controller action being called twice in rails applicaton

Tags: ruby-on-rails

"Why is the 'download_file' method in my Rails controller being called twice even though I only have one 'link_to' button triggering it? I have tried disabling turbolinks and callbacks but the issue persists and two credits are removed each time the download occurs. Here is the relevant code for my 'download_file' method and the link that triggers it:

```rb
#dashboard_controller.rb
def download_file
    puts "download_file method called"
    if current_account.credit < 1
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "You don't have enough credits to download this file."
    else
      puts current_account.credit
      current_account.credit -= 1
      current_account.save
      file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/test_file.zip", "r")
      self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/zip"
      self.response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename='test_file.zip'"
      self.response_body = file
    end
  end

#routes.rb
get 'download_file', to: 'dashboard#download_file', as: 'download_file'

#dashboard>show.html.erb
<%= link_to "Download", download_file_path, class: "download-button" %>
```

Comment: Please add the web console output from when you click the link to after the second credit is taken out.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and it took me a while to find a solution. On my end, the issue I was facing was related to turbolinks. By applying the solution described here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14310416), it fixed the issue.

In your case, if using Rails 5, try to update the link_to this way

```
<%= link_to "Download", download_file_path, class: "download-button", data: { turbolinks: false } %>
```